# How to rotate parent SKSpriteNode only and not the child node

Tags: sprite-kit

I have an `SKSpriteNode` that has a single child `SKSpriteNode`. When i rotate the parent node (with `SKAction` `rotateByAngle`), the child node is also rotated. I've tried quite a few things (setting child's `zRotation` to 0, setting `allowsRotation=NO`, even doing those things in `didSimulatePhysics`), but the child still rotates with the parent. How can i prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
node.parent.rotation = 90;
node.rotation = -90;
```

Basically just set the child's rotation to the inverse of the parent's rotation.

Comment: I thought of inverting, but it's not that simple in my case. I have a sequence of actions that also waits and then rotates for like 4 seconds, and waits and so on. I guess i could try creating the same inverse action in the sequence, but i was just hoping that there's a better way :/

Comment: well you can run a forever repeating runBlock action on the child that just does: node.rotation = -parent.rotation;

Comment: You could create an invisible node that serves as the parent for both.  That way, you just rotate the node you want and it should not affect other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If the child node's position is (0, 0), you will need to adjust only its rotation. If the child is not at the origin, you will need to adjust its position and rotation to account for the rotation of its parent. Here's an example of how to do that (in Swift):

Calculate and store the angle and radius of the child relative to its parent

```
    let dx = child.position.x
    let dy = child.position.y

    childAngle = atan2(dy, dx)
    childRadius = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
```

Adjust the child's position/rotation to counteract the rotation of the parent. This should be performed after all actions are evaluated.

```
override func didEvaluateActions() {
    let angle = node.zRotation
    let angleOffset = -angle + childAngle
    let x = childRadius * cos(angleOffset)
    let y = childRadius * sin(angleOffset)
    child.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
    child.zRotation = -angle
}
```